# OAuth 2.0 sample DotNetOpenAuth does not work

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I built the latest release of DotNetOpenAuth project from Github branches\v5.0\src\ and ran the OAuth2 sample app. I started from localhost:59722 to verify sample AuthorizationServer & ResourceServer. I had to make changes in three .cs files below to make the sample work. I'd appreciate if someone shed light on if there are known issues or I'm missing some config.

1. OAuthClient project : SampleWCF2.cs : Commented out Line 64:

   Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
2. Product/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2 project : AccessToken.cs : Commented out Line 54:

   Requires.That(signingKey == null || !signingKey.PublicOnly, "signingKey", "requires private key");
3. Product/DotNetOpenAth.OAuth2.Client project: OAuth2ClientChannel.cs Add in Line 102:

   ```
   //hack added to because contentType of text/html is returned for json
   if(contentType == "text/html" && body != null && body[0] == '{')
   {
       return this.DeserializeFromJson(body);
   }else if (contentType == JsonEncoded || contentType == JsonTextEncoded) {
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across an issue while running localhost. Mostly, it's because Facebook doesn't redirect to localhost. I had to add a line in my host file to fake a real domain.